# returning this from function in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have recently seen a question on stack overflow that how to get derived object from function,
some suggested that create local object and return copy from function. how about returning `this` from function?

I just wanna know, is that good coding practice?

Thank you for your assistance and time.

below is my example code.

```
class Base {
        public:
            virtual ~Base() {}
    };

    class Derived: public Base 
    {
        private:
            int i;
        public:
            Derived* func(int e) {
                i = e;
                return this;
            }

            int getI() { return i; }
    };
```

Comment: This would return a pointer to the existing `Derived`. Is this what you intend?

Comment: actually, i wanna know is that good practice or do we have any side effects by doing that?

Comment: There are no side effects, but you have the problem that you always have with pointers which is making sure that the object being pointed to lives at least as long as the pointer. In other words that you don't end up with a dangling pointer.

Comment: This is used in some cases for 'fluent' class interfaces, but in C++ there are references that make fluent interfaces much more readable. With a pointer return you can write `obj.Derived()->getI()' but if the return type was `Derived &` instead and the return was `return *this;`, then you could write `obj.Derived().getI()`

Comment: @DNT I understand that, we can return this from function, and i see the difference, you talking about, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your code like this

```
Derived d;
Derived* d_ptr = d.func(123);
```

Seems easier to just write this (assuming a suitable constructor)

```
Derived x(123);
Derived* x_ptr = &x;
```

But maybe you were thinking of something else.

Comment: the question i was referring to asked on stack overflow, was create object without using new operator

Comment: You can return a copy of the object as long as its copy constructor is not private or protected: `Derived func() { ... return Derived();}`. If no copy or move constructors have been defined, or appropriate ones defined, then the compiler would most likely optimize this to a move.

Comment: @DNT thanks your really helpful. how can accept your answers all are helpful

Comment: @VenkataCharyPadala You create objects by declaring variables, or by use of the constructor to create temporaries (like DNT suggests).

Answer (score 1):

```
Derived d;
Derived* d_ptr = d.func(123);
```

why not d_ptr = &d; 
whey d.func returns this？  when use d.func,  user have the pointer of d. no need to return again.  may be want to use in chain like d.func（1）->func(2)->func(3)

Answer (score 1):

Several operators used to return self reference (but not pointer):

- copy/move assignment
- pre increment/decrement
- `operator +=`, `operator -=`, ...

mainly to mimic built-in behavior.

That allows to chain operation: `a = b = c = 42;` (instead of `c = 42; b = c; a = b;`).

(Abusing of) chaining is not necessary more readable, and split in several statements may be clearer.

The pro-chaining also apply it to setter:

```
rectangle.set_height(42).set_width(21).set_position(x, y);
```

About pointer versus reference, returning pointer implies generally that `nullptr` is possible value (else reference is better).

operators which might return pointer are (address of) `operator&` and arrow `operator->`.

Behavior of default `&` already returns `this`, so no need to overload it to return `this`.

`operator->` should, at the end, returns a pointer; `this` might be a valid choice depending of the wrapper class.